# CKEditor Widget - prevent editing of the editable element itself

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I have a widget whereby the text of a link is editable. Users can edit the text of the link, however when users click on that link the standard link dialog is opened. I do not want that and was in understanding that an editable makes it possible to edit its innerHtml, not the element itself. How can I prevent this from happening?

**Widget plugin.js:**

```
template: 
  '<div class="container">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">' +
      'Label' +
    '</a>' +
  '</div>',

allowedContent:
  'a[*](*); div(*);',

editables: {
  Link: {
    selector: '.link',
    allowedContent: 'strong'
    }
 }
```

**Startup:**

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1;
CKEDITOR.inline( 'myId', {
  startupFocus: false
} );
```

CKEditor version: 4.5.9, Mode: Inline, Browser: Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think that your widget doesn't work at all, because if a link is inside a widget it should not be editable at all – neither its attributes nor its content.

The fact that any of these is editable, means that your widget wasn't discovered as a widget. Most likely due to issues in some other place in your code.

Comment: Widget works just fine. I added the CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1; and that made the link editable